# Installed chatbot but getting Error while importing ChatBot

Tags: python, chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os

bot = ChatBot('Bot')
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

for files in os.listdir('D:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/chatterbot_corpus/data/english'):
    data = open('D:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/chatterbot_corpus/data/english' + files, 'r').readlines()
    bot.train(data)
while True:
    message = input('You')
    if message.strip() != 'Bye':

        reply = bot.get_response(message)
        print('ChatBot :', reply)
    if message.strip() == 'Bye':
        print('ChatBot : Bye')
        break
```

I'm getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\nakulmagotra\Desktop\chatbot_train.py", line 1, in 
>       from chatterbot import ChatBot ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'

I'm a complete noob to Chatterbot .
Thanks.

Comment: and i have run the command python -m chatterbot --version in cmd it displays 1.0.2 and im working in anaconda3 with jupyter text editor. I'm a complete noob to pyhton and programming with python

Comment: Maybe you have not installed `chatterbot` in Anaconda. Open anaconda prompt and type `pip install chatterbot`

Comment: maybe start from how venv works in python

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot#installation), you should install it by `pip install chatterbot` or setup manually with `git clone https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot` and into the cloned directory run `python setup.py install`. After that, you can simply check it by using `import chatterbot` and see if it showing error or not.

Answer (score 1):

This Error Maybe due to Some reason.

- chatter is not installed try pip install chatterbot
- You are using a different environment. try to change the environment
- chatterbot is not in the path

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the previous version of ChatterBot.

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

This should work, unless there are some other problems. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

There would be another problem if you are using Python 3.8.x  . In Python 3.8.x, a few functions of a few modules were removed.
You will be able to import ChattberBot , but when you name the bot, there will be an error.

```
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>
time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Copy the location for the file given in the last line, where the error occurs.

```
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py
```

Open file with IDLE or whatever editor you have. Please do Not open the file directly(this will run the file, and you will not be able to see the code) , instead Open with IDLE or Your Text editor
Then , go to line 264  in that . It would be written

```
time_func = time.clock
```

Instead of this change it to

```
time_func = time.perf_counter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in pycharm
Write pip install chatterbox
Then one error may occur that time has no module clock
To fix it
Copy the location of last error
Then open it on pycharm not open it directly
Go in line no.264
And change it time clock() to time per_counter